# First line is missed when reading from a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file as follows:

```
Steve, assign tasks
Bob, register users
```

Using the code:

```
for n in textfile:
    strip_task = n.strip()
    split_task = n.split(", ")
    read_tasks = "\n"
    read_tasks += f"Task: \t{split_task[1]}"
```

It prints 'register users'

But I need it to also print the second line from the first sentence.

It seems to be only be reading from the second line in the text document even though after printing 'textfile' as its own it'll print the whole file as:

```
['Steve, assign tasks\n', 'Bob, register users']
```

I've checked the length of the text doc and it's reading as two so why is it only reading once in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you overwrite the variable `read_tasks` in each iteration.

You can solve the problem by defining the variable outside the loop as an empty string, and then add strings to the variable in the for loop:

```
read_tasks = ""
for n in textfile:
    strip_task = n.strip()
    split_task = n.split(", ")
    read_tasks += "\n"
    read_tasks += f"Task: \t{split_task[1]}"
```